# Vue component pb with functions from vuex file

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

When i use one of my functions situated in vuex js file, this error appear in the console.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4xY0.png]

Here's the code of the function in the vuex js file :

```js
mutations: {
    getPdfByReportId(reportId)
    {
        axios(
        {
            url:"http://localhost:9080/api/pdf/"+reportId,
            method:"GET", 
            responseType:'blob'
        }).then(response => 
        {
            //Download the pdf
            const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
            const link = document.createElement('a')
            link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            link.download = "report.pdf"
            link.click()
            URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href)
        });
    },
```

and here's where i use it :

````js
<v-icon style="cursor:pointer;" class="rounded-circle" @click="this.$store.commit('getPdfByReportId', item.reportId)" v-bind="props">mdi-download</v-icon>```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! For us to better help you, you must include the relevant parts of your code. And don't use screenshots for snippets/ error messages. You should also explain what you've tried so far, and specifically what is not working. Without more information, it is impossible to answer this question. For more information, see **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: Although, strait away I can see that this is a [CORS error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors), the browser is blocking the request to the server, as it's either not allowed, or doesn't include the correct headers.

Comment: Code is still not visible....

Comment: Is it good now ?

Comment: And how can i allow the browser to accept request on the CorsConfig file ?

Comment: Most likely by adding your client-side's URL to the server's accept headers, like with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. But this depends on your situation, I recommend Googling it to learn more, or read [this article](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9)